# Passing DOM element to controller when using jquery autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using ASP.Net MVC and JQuery UI autocomplete.

I have a number of input-boxes set up in a table and I have this JavaScript code.

```
    $('.searchfield').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutoCompleteFunction")'
    });
```

Which works perfectly. The controller reads from a database and returns a list of matches.

Now I have another column of fields that also need autocomplete. However, these autocomplete lists have to be dependent on what is already in the table.

How can I pass DOM elements to the autocomplete controller?

I have tried something like this. As long as I only pass a string it will work, but not when I try to pass it a DOM element.

```
$('.newsearch').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("NewAutoCompleteFunction", new { firstParameter = "testing"})'.replace("testing", "'$document.activeElement.value'")
});
```

Comment: What DOM element you want to pass and more importantly why? Autocomplete is supposed to retrive records based on a term, why would you like to pass objects?

Comment: I am setting up a table where you search up elements in order to populate it. Some elements are dependent on what is already there, so I want to pass text from other table elements in order to change the autocomplete list in the current field.

Comment: To narrow it down even further. When I have a bunch of input boxes with autocomplete in a table, how can the controller know _which_ of them is being used?